# Android Studio - What is this "grey git rectangle" that looks like a "git branch" in the working directory?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

Looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/6fcb3652c600c1ffabc01721b24a75e7

Not sure what I did.. I thought I created a new branch.

But..it's not green/I can't checkout or even delete with `git branch --delete <branch>`. What is this and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have added a tag.

You can remove it with `git tag -d tagname`

Comment: Thanks! while we're at it, how do you create a tag (without terminal commands) in android studio? Not sure how I did it